# Can I create virtual directory in AppHarbor?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, iis, appharbor

I have a website currently on my local IIS (a separate website like "Default Web site"). I added an folder inside it and right clicked and did a "Convert to Application". This means now it is completely separate application which has it's own web.config and doesn't interfere with main web.config.

Can I achieve the same in [AppHarbor](https://appharbor.com/)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably run this as a separate application on AppHarbor. Please provide additional details on your use case if that's not a good solution for you.

Comment: That doesn't work for me. I have a main application like http://something.com. Now I am trying to integrate a 3rd party CMS which should be a separate application and shouldn't interfere with my main application of http://something.com. However, this 3rd party should run under URL http://something.com/cms. Please suggest how can I achieve that.

Comment: No, I'm afraid that's not currently supported.